# Rellenar manualmente Chart en ASPX

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estoy probando a rellenar un Chart con datos manuales, el codigo que he intentado es el siguiente:

```
int[,] horas = new int[,] { { 0, 1 },{ 1, 1 }, { 2, 0 }, { 3, 1 }, { 4, 0 }, { 5, 1 } };

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Chart1.Series.Clear();
    Chart1.DataSource = horas;
    var series1 = new Series
    {
        Name = "Prueba1",
        Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green,
        IsVisibleInLegend = true,
        IsXValueIndexed = true,
        ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line           
    };
    series1.AxisLabel = "Axis";        


    for (int i = 0; i < horas.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        series1.Points.AddXY(horas[i,0],horas[i,1]);
    }

    Chart1.DataBind();

}
```

Sin embargo no sale nada en la pagina, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes añadir la serie al gráfico:

```
Chart1.Series.Add(series1);
```

Comment: Cierto, se me olvido lo mas basico!